# ClojureScript function prints strings, but will not return hiccup

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have a ClojureScript component:

```clj
(defn main-panel []

  (def nodes (-> @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/nodes])))

  (defn list-nodes [node]
    (prn (node :name)))

  (reagent/create-class
   {:component-did-mount
    (fn []
      (api-service/get-file-tree))

    :reagent-render
    (fn []
      (doseq [node nodes]
        (if (= (node :depth) 0)
          (list-nodes node))))}))
```

which prints strings to the console.

But when I change the first function to:

```clj
  (defn list-nodes [node]
    [:<>
     [:h1 (node :name)]])
```

I don't get any HTML that is rendered -  no errors and the browser window stays blank.

How can I change this so it renders html?

## Update

In response to the answer below I have changed `doseq` for `for`.
The issue is now that I am getting the error `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child` which is fine if you're working with React because you can debug, but with reagent, not so much. consider the following. This function:

```clj
(defn node [nodes]
  (prn (nodes :name)))
```

when called by this function:

```clj
    :reagent-render
    (fn []
      (for [nodes all-nodes]
        (if (= (nodes :depth) 0)
          (do
            (nodeComponent/node nodes)
            ))))
```

prints 5 strings. But changing the called function to this:

```clj
(defn node [nodes]
  [:h1 (nodes :name)])
```

causes this error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child`.

Is this problem somehow related to [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906528/on-click-renders-as-text?noredirect=1#comment102234091_57906528) I'm having?

Answer (score 2):

For one, `def` and `defn` create global bindings.  In order to create local bindings, use `let` or `letfn`:

```
(defn main-panel []
  (let [nodes (-> @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/nodes]))
    (letfn [(list-nodes [node]
              (prn (node :name)))]
      (reagent/create-class
       {:component-did-mount
        (fn []
          (api-service/get-file-tree))
        :reagent-render
        (fn []
          (doseq [node nodes]
            (if (= (node :depth) 0)
              (list-nodes node))))}))
```

Your problem is that the render function should return the hiccup forms, but `doseq` returns `nil`.  The function inside gets run (that's why you see console output from `prn`), but its return value is thrown away (that's why you see no HTML).  An immediate fix might be to replace `doseq` with `for`, but

You could maybe do it like this (first reagent form):

```
(defn main-panel []
  [:ul (for [node @(re-frame/subscribe [::subs/nodes])
             :when (zero? (:depth node))]
         ^{:key (:id node)} ; whatever identifies nodes, for performance
         [:li {:class "node"} (:name node)]])
```

I would trigger data fetching not here but wherever you startup your application (more or less parallel to the initial app render step).

Comment: Thanks @Svante - but why would that make a difference and how do you propose I use `let` or `letfn` in this instance to make it work? `:<>` is just hiccup for a [React fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) and should not make a difference used in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @Svante - I don't want to return a list or unordered list, I'm just trying to render a function containing hiccup for every `node` I pass it - I've tried changing the the `doseq` to a `for`, but I get `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React`.

Comment: Again, you need to actually _return_ the hiccup forms from your render function.

Comment: Thanks, but I just can't get it to work. I think I am returning hiccup, but I'm not and I don't know why. `nodeComponent/node nodes` calls function `node` which has *only* hiccup in it. I've even tried putting hiccup straight in to `:reagent-render` as the last form in the function.