# :on-click renders as text

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

My ClojureScript function:

```clj
(defn node-function [node]
  [:<>
   [:div (node :name) {:on-click #(prn "hi")}]])
```

renders as HTML text in the DOM:

```
My Documents{:on-click #object[Function]}
```

My code looks exactly the same as `:on-click` examples I've found online.

Why does the compiler think this is text and not a function?

Comment: can you link to the example you are following? :)

Comment: Sure - https://reagent-project.github.io/ - search for `on-c`.

Comment: Alright, looks ok as you say. I'm not familiar with `[:<>` though what does it do/ why is it needed?.

Comment: Thanks @JonasJohansson. `[:<>` is hiccup for a shorthand [React fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

Comment: hmm, now I'm grasping here but can it be that you are using node as a function name and as a parameter and somewhere compiler gets confused?

Comment: Thanks but didn't fix :(

Comment: that's because you made the map a child of the react fragment rather than props of an element

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith - could you provide a link to some documentation on how to do this correctly?

Comment: How about the documentation [you yourself linked](https://reagent-project.github.io/) in your other question? As you can see, the props map (corresponds to React props) is always the first argument to the hiccup form. It's not actually all that clear what you want here, especially since you have the same name for both your function and it's argument.

Comment: Thanks! So what you're saying is swap the order of the map and the list in the div - it works!! :) I'm trying to execute a function on click. Thank you.

Comment: Please add the above to an answer - in React the order of props don't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how the rest of your project is structured, but it looks like the property map and inner html of the `div` you're trying to render are transposed.

The reason that the rendered model appears that way is that reagent sees that the first child of the `:div` vector is not a map (it is a String, presumably) and interprets all remaining children as intended additional children of the emitted `div` in the html, stringifying them as it goes.

You're likely looking for a function defined more like this:

```clj
(defn node-function [node]
  [:div {:on-click #(prn "hi")} (:name node)])
```

---

I removed the `:<>` bit because it isn't needed here due to there only being one `div` in this component.

I transposed the `node` and `:name` to be a little more nil-safe and to make the lookup of name more clearly a lookup.

Comment: Point of interest `:<>` in Reagent generates a [Fragment](https://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/ReactFeatures.html) for if you need to render multiple elements without a containing element. You are correct it's not needed here, but if his component has multiple divs, he'd need one.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know! I've edited the answer accordingly.