# What is the correct way to dynamically render components in reagent?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent

Dynamically rendering components in React is fundamental to its use. It's very easy to do as can be seen here:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="blocks_loop">
        {this.props.blocks.map(block => (
          <div className="block" />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

In this example you will get as many divs rendered as there are `blocks`. I am trying to achieve the same thing with reagent, part of which I've documented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903325/clojurescript-function-prints-strings-but-will-not-return-hiccup/57904128#57904128) post.  There are examples out there of people doing it like [this](https://blog.ducky.io/clojurescript/reagent/2016/05/11/reagent-dynamic-children/) one, but they all seem to include the use of `lists` which I don't want to use - it just doesn't suit my purpose. I just want as many components out as items I put in.

### Update

I now have this code trying to follow the answer below which is meant to render 3 divs for every key value pair in `my-map`. Nothing is rendered and it throws the error `react-dom.development.js:507 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.`:

```clj
(ns mapping-test.views
  (:require
   [re-frame.core :as re-frame]
   [mapping-test.subs :as subs]))

(defn main-panel []

  (def my-map {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})

  (defn a-component []
    [:h1 "This is a component rendering"])

  (defn my-loop [my-map]
    (for [value my-map]
      [a-component]))

  (fn []
    [my-loop my-map]))
```

Comment: "they just doesn't work for any kind of serious application" citation needed.

Comment: Ok, maybe someone used one once, but can you answer the question? ;)

Comment: If the "question" boils down to "please translate this javascript code to ClojureScript", no, we don't do that here (without someone showing their own good-faith effort and a specific, narrow problem); plenty of references on [meta] available to that effect, see in particular [Is "How do I convert code from this language to this language too broad?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296119). Show what you *tried* to do in ClojureScript and the specific failure mode encountered.

Comment: (And when amending this -- please be very explicit about what you mean in saying you're trying to avoid "the use of `lists`", and what you'd expect a solution that *doesn't* do that to look like instead. If you consider any kind of sequence a list, I don't understand how you'd store or pass a variable number of items *without* some kind of sequence type storing it).

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy - no I'm not looking for anyone to translate my code here. I come from a js background and am trying to learn ClojureScript. My point was that with react (I'm using reagent which is obviously its ClojureScript incarnation), there is an easy, standard and well documented approach to this as in the code example I've given. After spending serious amounts of time trying to achieve the same with ClojureScript, I haven't been able to do it, it's just error after error as you can see in my post I link to. When I say `lists`, obviously I don't mean Clojure lists, I mean html elements.

Comment: html / hiccup (list / <li>) elements in the Clojure example I link to.

Comment: @Mr.Robot I thought you meant Clojure lists. And even for `<ul>` and `<ol>` still, citation needed. I bet you can find those tags on at least half of the top 100 websites on the internet. In fact, if you're a React developer I'd bet dimes to dollars they're in some of your own work, used by UI component libraries that you've included.

Answer (score 7):

```
(defn my-component [blocks]
   [:div.blocks_loop
     (for [b blocks]
       [:div.block])])
```

Since you are creating hiccup, you can just use any clojure code to map or loop through your data.

Comment: Notably, `blocks` here is a sequence. When the OP says they don't want "the use of `lists`", does that mean they don't want any sequence types at all? (I honestly don't know what they're asking, so I don't know if this answer, or any other, fulfills it).

Comment: I think it's just the language barrier. And for beginners things like building hiccup "dynamically" is not obvious. Luckliy SO has a vote button ;)

Comment: Thanks for the straightforward answer @JochenBedersdorfer - again, when I said lists, I was referring to `html / hiccup / jsx` like in the link I provided and not `lists` as in Clojure data structures. So if I wanted to loop through an actual component (in a separate function) could I replace your line of code `[:div.block])])` with something like `[function-returning-hiccup])])`?

Comment: sure. That's how you nest components in hiccup. Just use the name.

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation for when to use [] vs() in hiccup: http://reagent-project.github.io/docs/master/UsingSquareBracketsInsteadOfParens.html

Comment: Thanks @JochenBedersdorfer I still can't get this component to render. I have updated the question.

Comment: At least one issue is that you are not returning proper hiccup running `my-loop`.
Also, you are defining top level functions within the `main-panel` function.
I suggest using the shadow-cljs/re-frame starter template to get going

Comment: here's the starter template: https://github.com/Day8/re-frame-template

That should hopefully make it clearer how to use components

Comment: Should be wrapped in a `doall` to force evaluation and you can add a `^{:key b}` before `[:div.block]` to prevent the "every element should have a unique index" warning

Comment: Yes on the ^key, but I don't think a `doall` is necessary. Reagent works just fine with lazy sequences. But maybe you are referring to something else